# Android crash log annotation

Tags: android, crash, crash-reports

Is it possible for an Android application to add additional lines to a crash log before it actually crashes in order to send better debugging information back to the developers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Fabric or firebase crash analytics. They will provide you the crash logs.

[image]

In your onCreate

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; import android.os.Bundle; import android.view.Menu; import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics; import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity { 
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
   }
}
```

Use the link below to integrate crash analytics in your app

https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install