# Unabled to get device information in sentry crash report

Tags: java, android, sentry

I am working on one project and i integrate Sentry for generate crash report but in console of sentry does not get details of device version or OS name but in iOS it display.But why i don't know.It's supported in Android? Please Help me.

Comment: Use Fabric it will provide you the full details about device https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091581/android-crash-log-annotation/49091855#49091855

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in your application context via the `AndroidSentryClientFactory` as described here: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/modules/android/

`Context ctx = this.getApplicationContext();
Sentry.init(sentryDsn, new AndroidSentryClientFactory(ctx));`